# Create SharePoint List View to show last N items

Tags: list-view, list-view-threshold

I have one list i.e-**Tickets** which is having more then 300K records. There are more than 10 views, now no one view showing items but it is giving threshold limit warning. Threshold limit we set as 80K.

Only **ID column is indexed** in this list which is by default, now i want to show last 5000 items which is obviously based on the ID column. I checked, list view only shows items if filter expression uses ID column.

Comment: which version of SP are you using?

Comment: I am using SP 2013

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set order by ID desc in view? And set the number of returning values to 5000. Thus you'll get last 5000 items.

Comment: I did that before and it gave me same threshold warning. I guess until we use filter parameters in the View, it will not return exact items.

Comment: You need to have a filter that returns less than 5000 items. The Order you propose would be processed after the filtering stage. Thus it is to late to circumvent the limit.

Comment: Make sure to only use the ID field in the lower section. No additional filtering/grouping/Counting of records is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom search result webpart. After search result webpart in a blank page edit the quary to show only item in your path. Order your return by created date. You will have to deal with search update schedule but it works for a really large items number list. You can also customize the result template using HTML ang got a really reach and fancy result grid